# 5! is 120, but output reads 1! is 120?

Tags: java, while-loop, factorial

Instructions: Write a program that lets a user enter N and that outputs N! (meaning N*(N-1)*(N-2)*...*2*1). Hint: Initialize a variable totalValue to N, and use a loop variable i that counts from N-1 down to 1.

From my understanding of Java factorials, 5! = 5*4*3*2*1 = 120.
So as I'm calculating a Java factorial in this exercise, I typed in 5 as a user input to test whether I was able to correctly calculate a Java factorial. But the output comes out as 1! is 120. Here is part of my code, just to get a glimpse:

```
 userInt = scnr.nextInt(); 
 // FIXME: Ask user to input an integer, store in userInt

 totalVal = userInt;

 while (userInt > 1) {
     userInt = userInt - 1;
     totalVal = userInt * totalVal;

 }   // FIXME: Add while loop that counts down to 1, updating totalVal
 System.out.println(userInt + "! is " + totalVal);
 } //After typing 5 and clicking Run, it shows 1! is 120
```

From my understanding of the comment //FIXME: Ask user to input an integer, store in userInt//, I typed in '5' as a test for trying to calculate the factorial. So in typing 5 as the user input, why didn't it come out to being 5! is 120? Why isn't it 5! is 120?

Is it possible to explain from my code as to why it's 1! is 120 rather than 5! is 120? Or why it should be 5! is 120 as I've been assuming it to be?
Thank you in advance, I'm trying to wrap my head around this.

Comment: Because you're decrementing `userInt` until it reaches 1. What's confusing to you?

Comment: When decrementing, correct me if I'm wrong, that's to say, i = i -1? So that's to say in my code it is 1! is 120 because of userInt = userInt - 1? It makes sense now as to why it's 1! is 120. I was confused at first because I thought 5! = 5*4*3*2*1 = 120, and I assumed that the output should have shown up as 5! is 120

Comment: That's exactly right.

Comment: You can use `for` instead of `while`

Answer (score 3):

You're decrementing `userInt` until it reaches 1. You can fix this by adding and using a holder integer variable.

```
userInt = scnr.nextInt(); 

int holder = userInt;

totalVal = userInt;

while (userInt > 1) {
 userInt = userInt - 1;
 totalVal = userInt * totalVal;

}   // FIXME: Add while loop that counts down to 1, updating totalVal
System.out.println(holder + "! is " + totalVal);
} //After typing 5 and clicking Run, it shows 1! is 120
```

Answer (score 0):

After while loop, userInt became 1

userInt = userInt - 1; <= repeats until it becomes 1

backup userInt in another variable.

Answer (score 0):

You are mutating your userInt variable in your while loop, so it will always print 1 when it's time to print.

Store user int in a different variable before your while loop and print that instead.